# Subtracting a sequence of numbers using for loop in C Programming

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, subtraction, function-definition

```
int myfunc(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a;
    for(int index = a - 1; index >= b; index--)
    {
        result -= index;
    }
    return result;
}
```

How to make this function subtract numbers from the smallest number to the greatest number depending on the values of a and b that I choose ?  (e.g. if a = 5 and b = 8 , then the program would type 5-6-7-8 = -16)

Answer (score 1):

You're going the "wrong direction".  Look at what you want to do:

```
5-6-7-8 = -16
^ ^ ^ ^
a | | |
 a+1| |
   a+2|
     a+3
```

So start at `a+1` and count *up* to `b`

```
int result = a;
for(int index = a + 1; index <= b; index++)
{
    result -= index;
}
// result = -16 for a=5, b=8
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GMMEsczKn)

Answer (score 0):

For starters the variable `index` is redundant.

To avoid an overflow (at least in most cases) the variable `result` should have the type `long long int` instead of `int`. For example if you will run your function like

```
myfunc( INT_MIN , INT_MIN + 3 );
```

(provided that you have included the header `<limits.h>`) when if the type of the variable `result` is `int` then the function will return the value `-6` (actually the behavior is undefined in this case) while if the variable `result` has the type `long long int` then you will get the correct result `4294967290`.

The function can look the following way

```
long long int myfunc( int a, int b )
{
    if ( b < a )
    {
        int tmp = b;
        b = a;
        a = tmp;
    }
 
    long long int result = a;

    while ( a < b )
    {
        result -= ++a;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int myfunc( int a, int b )
{
    if ( b < a )
    {
        int tmp = b;
        b = a;
        a = tmp;
    }
 
    long long int result = a;

    while ( a < b )
    {
        result -= ++a;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%lld\n", myfunc( 8, 5 ) );
 
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
-16
```